# Dealing with in/out string parameters in Swig Python

Tags: python, c++, pointers, swig

Maybe someone know, how to rewrite *getVersion* to get in Python *version* and *legacyVersion* as a result of function instead of passing them as *in/out* parameters

```
   class DeviceInterface {
   public:
      virtual uint32_t getVersion(uint8_t* version, uint8_t* legacyVersion ) = 0;
   };
```

For now I create additional function in SWIG inteface file, but current implementation returns only one parameter instead of two.

```
%ignore DeviceInterface::getVersion( uint8_t* version, uint8_t* legacyVersion );

%extend DeviceInterface {
    virtual char * getVersion() {
        static uint8_t _v[200];
        static uint8_t _lv[200];
        $self->getVersion(_v, _lv);
        return (char *)_lv;
    }
};
```

**UPDATE**

Now I use *@ignore* and *@extend* features. But I guess there is more elegant way. Here is my working SWIG interface snippet:

```
%extend DeviceInterface {
    virtual PyObject *getVersion() {
        static uint8_t _v[200];
        static uint8_t _lv[200];
        uint32_t libCode = $self->getVersion(_v, _lv);
        return Py_BuildValue("(l,s,s)", libCode, (char *)_v, (char *)_lv);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own typemaps to handle the output parameters.  In this case, the typemaps treat *all* `uint32_t*` parameters as 200-byte output buffers.  This is a minimal example without error checking.

```cpp
%module test

%include <stdint.i>

// Require no input parameter.  Just allocate a fixed-sized buffer.
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) uint8_t* %{
    $1 = new uint8_t[200];
%}

// Free the temporary buffer when done converting the argument
%typemap(freearg) uint8_t* %{
    delete [] $1;
%}

// On output, convert the buffer to a Python byte string
%typemap(argout) uint8_t* %{
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, PyBytes_FromString(reinterpret_cast<char*>($1)));
%}

// Example implementation
%inline %{
#include <stdint.h>
class DeviceInterface {
public:
    virtual uint32_t getVersion(uint8_t* version, uint8_t* legacyVersion ) {
        strcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(version),"1.0.0");
        strcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(legacyVersion),"2.0.0");
        return 0;
    }
};
%}
```

Output:

```
>>> import test
>>> d=test.DeviceInterface()
>>> d.getVersion()
[0, b'1.0.0', b'2.0.0']
```

Note the output is a concatenation  of the return value and two output parameters.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Could I go the same way but with output array of C++ structures, e.g. `uint32_t getJobs(Jobs *array, uint8_t &jobsCount)` where struct Job has several primitive type fields and uint8_t byte buffer. If yes, what API should I use instead of `PyBytes_FromString` to pach the sctructure.

Comment: And another question. Are the any drawbacks in my implementation in comparison with yours?

Comment: @Den with a typemap it is automatically applied to any function with a `uint32_t*` parameter, but that can be limited with named parameters and `%apply`. Your method would have to individually ignore and extend each function.  For your other question the answer is yes but ask a new SO question for a code example answer.

Comment: [here is it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70534022/swig-python-c-struct-as-in-out-parameter) :) Many thanks